# How to remove post archive posts description/excerpt from wordpress website?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

How to remove post archive posts description/excerpt from wordpress website?
See the screenshot: http://tinypic.com/r/1zq5zc7/8

I already tried this code, but it did not work for me.

```
.archive .post-content p {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Share the link to your website. Having a look at your HTML could be helpful.

Comment: thanks for your reply. i already solved my problem using .post-meta